# Should I write tests that directly map input to output, or dynamically generate a result?

Tags: language-agnostic, testing, conventions

It seems to me that there are two ways to write test cases:

1. Map fixed inputs to fixed outputs and assert that they match
2. Map generated or fixed inputs to dynamic outputs and assert that they match

---

```
# Static testing:
assert_equal "test".upcase, "TEST"

# Dynamic testing:
assert_equal person.full_name, "#{person.title} #{person.first_name} #{person.last_name}"
```

---

Of course there are pros and cons to each approach. Duplicating implementation details feels wrong, but allows me to generate sample data and run tests on it. Hard coding values makes the correct output very explicit, but doesn't seem to lend it self to reusing code.

Is the former the conventional way to write tests? Do you mix and match approaches? Is the latter method avoided for a good reason that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach, using tools like [check](http://check.sourceforge.net/) or [quickcheck](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_QuickCheck), but...

> Duplicating implementation details
>   feels wrong

If your duplicating then you're doing it wrong.  In your code you write what the task is and how how the task is performed to a precise degree.  In the test you give some invariants about the result.

**EDIT**

**A note on Known Answer Tests (KATs)**

Like most generalizations, there are situations where this doesn't apply.  One big area where KATs are dominant over random test vectors is cryptography (e.g. block ciphers) because there aren't supposed to be many visible invariants outside of what most type systems enforce (ex: block size).  One property to check would be `decrypt(key,encrypt(key,msg)) == msg`.

Simple geometry has a somewhat different problem in that no set of invariants is really a good check - you can say `0 < area(triangle) < triangle.width * triangle.height` but that's just as bad.  What I'm getting at here is you should be writing tests for a slightly higher level of code - something more complex that actually have a good chance of changing or being deceptively wrong.

**Situations For Random Test Vectors**
Some properties of code that indicate a good place for quick check properties include

1. determinism
2. Non-trivial
3. clear invariants

Trivial example using concatenation (combining two lists in series to form one new list):

Say I have a function `concat(xs,ys) = xs ++ ys`.  What can I check? Anything I expect to be true!  Length?  Yes!  Elements?  Yes!

```
prop_len(xs,ys) = len(xs) + len(ys) = len(concat(xs,ys))
prop_elem(xs,ys) =
    let cs = concat(xs,ys)
    elem(head xs, cs) && elem(head ys, cs) && prop_elem(tail xs,ys) && prop_elem(xs,tail ys)
// Yes, I left out the error checking for empty list, sue me.
```

Get the drift?

Comment: My dynamic test example relied directly on a combination of methods. What if, for example, I want to test that a method correctly calculates the area of a triangle? Should I use fixed inputs and outputs, or implement duplicated code to calculate the area in the test *and* the method being called? Is this what you mean by 'doing it wrong' - that I should hard code values in these kinds of test cases?

Answer (score 1):

I generally use the second approach as I'd have a bunch of variables declared above the assertions that I might want to change some day.


I think you have to ask yourself which way makes it clearer how to implement the method call.  For me it's easily the second approach.  For unit tests this usually makes sense.


In acceptance tests however the first approach seems to be used much more frequently.  Most recently I have had to verify that an image coming back from an API call is correct.  I could try to construct the image based on the inputs given to me, or I could have a reference image.  This means that the acceptance test isn't finished before the code though, and I have to keep manually checking the image until dev work is finished.  However once the image is 'correct' I still have something to stop regressions.


Generally I think it's up to you to decide which approach works well for the test you are writing.